# how to extract the contents of a table based on the column value?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a table with values . I want to extact the rows that has a particular column value using UNIX. Below is my table.

filenumber appln date msg

```
12 , ADRJH , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
12 , AHW , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
92 , AIWEFEWMS , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
66 , AIWEMS , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
3 , CCWEA , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
3 , CCWEA , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
85 , CCWEDB , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
85 , CCYHDB , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
5 , GENESTUHTYS , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
3 , GTTGXS , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
3 , GXUIKS , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
1 , MDUJM , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
1 , MDYUJM , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
5 , medsUYJYapecc , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
4 , medsapeYUcc , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
262 , MYUJIF , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
262 , MIUJF , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
805 , PYUI , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
423 , PI_TYCHARGEBACK , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
434 , PI_CHYUJHYUARGEBACK , 2014-12-03 , SUCCESS
4 , PomnituYUJre , 2014-12-02 , SUCCESS
```

I need the rows with date as 2014-12-03 . Which unix command can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use

> grep '/<2014-12-03/>' file

the "\<" and "\>" will trigger grep to search exactly for fixed pattern as a "word" than the pattern being a part of a "word"

Also if you find that using markers "\<" and "\>" are a bit difficult you can try the easier way

```
grep -F '2014-12-03' file
```

-F argument will also search for a fixed string

if you want grep to highlight the fixed string found in the lines in a **terminal**

> grep '/<2014-12-03/>' --color file

or

```
grep -F '2014-12-03' --color file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
grep '\b2014-12-03\b' file
```

or

```
awk '$4=="2014-12-03"{print}' file
```

or

```
awk '$4=="2014-12-03"' file
```